# Prevent user to input the script into wordpress post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am making a blog site. I want to prevent the user(all users even user type is administrator) to input any script tag into the wordpress post. If user input the script tag into the post then onclick of publish it should give the error message to the user or simply remove the the script tag from content. I am not much familiar with the wordpress. Please suggest me how i can do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: https://vip.wordpress.com/plugins/advanced-blacklist/
It can blacklist words. just add the words as `<script>` `<SCRIPT>`

Answer (score 0):

Setting

```
define( 'DISALLOW_UNFILTERED_HTML', true );
```

in `wp-config.php` is the recommended way to do this.

> **Why are some users allowed to post unfiltered HTML?**
>
> Users with Administrator or Editor roles are allowed to publish unfiltered HTML in post titles, post content, and comments. WordPress is, after all, a publishing tool, and people need to be able to include whatever markup they need to communicate. Users with lesser privileges are not allowed to post unfiltered content.
>
> If you are running security tests against WordPress, use a lesser privileged user so that all content is filtered. If you are concerned about an Administrator putting XSS into content and stealing cookies, note that all cookies are marked for HTTP only delivery, and are divided into privileged cookies used for admin pages, and unprivileged cookies used for public facing pages. Content is never displayed unfiltered in the admin. Regardless, an Administrator has wide-ranging super powers, among which unfiltered HTML is a lesser one.
>
> In WordPress Multisite, only the Super Admin can publish unfiltered HTML, as all other users are considered untrusted.
>
> To disable unfiltered HTML for all users, including administrators, you can add `define( 'DISALLOW_UNFILTERED_HTML', true );` to `wp-config.php`.

https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/testing/reporting-security-vulnerabilities/#why-are-some-users-allowed-to-post-unfiltered-html